# AbiFunctionNotFoundError: Function "mint" not found on ABI. Make sure you are using the correct ABI and that the function exists on it

Tags: solidity, ethers.js, abi, viem

I get this error when I call the mint() function

> "biFunctionNotFoundError: Function "mint" not found on ABI. Make sure
> you are using the correct ABI and that the function exists on it."
>
> I have checked my ABI a couple of times to make sure that everything
> is correct but I didn't find a solution

Here are the code snippets

**WriteContract.ts**

```
export class WriteContract implements IWriteContracts {


async _mint(id: bigint, value: bigint, to: Hash): Promise<Hash | string | void> {
    
    try {
    
        const result = await writeContract(config, {
        abi : abi,
        functionName : "mint", 
        address  : _contractAddress,
        args: [id, value, to],
      });
      return result

    } catch (error: any) {
      return error;
    }
     
    ...
}

//////////////////////////////////////////////
```

> Then I have called the method on my component

**Article.tsx**

```
const msgSender = useAccount({
   config,
})

const [_quantity, setQuantity] = useState<string>("0");
const { _mint } = new WriteContract()

// @bundle who manage the date we are sending to our smart contract logic
const Mint:Imint = {
    name : name,
    id : BigInt(id),
    price : parseFloat(price),
    quantitySelected : _quantity,
    totalAmount : parseFloat(price) * parseInt(_quantity)

}

// mint function who trigger the mint() on our smart contracts 
async function mintNFT() : Promise<void | string | bigint>  {
   
    if(parseInt(Mint.quantitySelected) > 3) {
        return "cannot mint more than 3 nft at time";
    }
    
   
    const tx = await _mint( Mint.id, BigInt(Mint.quantitySelected), msgSender.address as Hash)
    return tx
}  


return (
    <article className="flex items-center flex-col  gap-4 border border-dashed rounded-md p-2 mb-4 bg-neutral-50">
        <div>
            <h3>{name}</h3>
            <Badge variant="outline">{String(id)}</Badge>
        </div>
        <div>
            <Image src={img} alt="nft" width={170} height={170}/>    
        </div>
        <div>
            <Input placeholder="quantity"
            onChange={(e:React.ChangeEvent<HTMLInputElement>) => setQuantity(e.target.value)}
            />
            <p className="text-sm  mt-5">{price} Ξ</p>
        </div>
        <button
        onClick={() => mintNFT() }
        className="py-3 px-7  border rounded-md hover:bg-indigo-600 hover:opacity-70 hover:text-white"
        >
            mint
        </button>
    </article>
)
```

> Here is My mint function in my Abi :

**abi.ts**

```
 export const abi = [..., {
    "type": "function",
    "name": "mint",
    "inputs": [
      {
        "name": "id",
        "type": "uint256",
        "internalType": "uint256"
      },
      {
        "name": "value",
        "type": "uint256",
        "internalType": "uint256"
      },
      {
        "name": "to",
        "type": "address",
        "internalType": "address"
      }
    ],
    "outputs": [],
    "stateMutability": "payable"
  }, ...] as const
```

thanks for help!

Comment: Add details about the implementation of the writeContract function, especially how it interacts with the ABI and the smart contract, would help provide a more comprehensive understanding of the problem.